# Directories required for creating a folder tree

Tags: code-challenge

Say that you have this folder structure on your coumputer:

```
/a
```

And you want to have these folders:

```
/a/b
/a/c
/b/b
```

You would need to create four directories, using mkdir for example:

```
mkdir /a/b
mkdir /a/c
mkdir /b
mkdir /b/b
```

Write a program that, given existing and required directory structures, will output the directories that need to be created.

### Input

First line has two numbers: n, number of existing directories, and m, number of required directories
Next n lines has the list of existing directories
Next m lines has the list of required directories

Example:

```
1 3
/a
/a/b
/a/c
/b/b
```

### Output

Directories you need to create

Example:

```
/a/b
/a/c
/b
/b/b
```

Comment: Exact duplicate of ["File Fix-it codegolf (GCJ 2010 1B-A)"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2892126/file-fix-it-codegolf-gcj-2010-1b-a) from StackOverflow, which in turn came from Google Code Jam [Round 1B 2010](http://code.google.com/codejam/contest/dashboard?c=635101#s=p0).

Comment: @Joey, this one is not a code-golf, so we can write more efficient (cpu cycles) answers than in the SO question

Comment: errr... who wins, then? O:-)

Comment: @J B, probably not one that formats your harddrive :)

Comment: @gnibbler but how can you trust algorithmics when it's so easy to just try it out? O:-)

Answer (score 2):

## Python

In Python, you would just use `os.makedirs()`. See the docs at the bottom of this post

```py
import sys

num_existing, num_required = map(int, next(sys.stdin).split())

sep = "/"
directory = {}

for i,path in enumerate(s.rstrip("\n") for s in sys.stdin):
    d = directory    
    base = ""
    for p in path.split(sep)[1:]:
        base += sep+p
        if p not in d:
            if i >= num_existing:
                print base
            d[p]={}
        d = d[p]
```

Python docs for `os.makedirs()`

```py
>>> import os
>>> help(os.makedirs)

Help on function makedirs in module os:

makedirs(name, mode=511)
    makedirs(path [, mode=0777])
    
    Super-mkdir; create a leaf directory and all intermediate ones.
    Works like mkdir, except that any intermediate path segment (not
    just the rightmost) will be created if it does not exist.  This is
    recursive.
```

Comment: The challenge is not to create the dirs, only print the ones that need to be created. Nice find though!

Answer (score 2):

## Bash, <s>175</s> <s>169</s> <s>168</s> <s>135</s> <s>130</s> 128

Here's one of my worthwhile solutions from SO, then:

**WARNING:** Be sure to run in an empty directory, as this will wipe out its contents first thing per test.

```bsh
read t
for((;x++<t;));do
rm -r *
read n m
for((i=n+m;i--;));do
read d
mkdir -p .$d
done
echo Case \#$x: $[`find|wc -l`-n-1]
done
```